# what is address family unknown1 in winsock2.h?

Tags: windows-7, sockets

In the header file of winsock, I found an address family called unknown1. Here is the source code of the header file [winsock2.h](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mingw-org-wsl/ci/4.0.0/tree/include/winsock2.h), and here is the code line that contain the constant of that address family:

```
#define AF_UNKNOWN1 20
```

So, can anyone tell me what does this address family represents ?? And what is it used for ??

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).